# Phase difference between electrons emitted from a photoelectric setup of Cs

Tags: electrons, interference, photoelectric-effect

I read that electrons being emitted from a Cs plate when irradiated with photons with energy greater than work function of Cs, are used in a double slit experiment.
But, should they not have varying initial phases, such that visible interference can't occur due to constant variation of intensity at any point?

Comment: Maybe of use: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76692/is-coherent-light-required-for-interference-in-youngs-double-slit-experiment

Answer (score 0):

> should they not have varying initial phases

Yes they should and they do. But this is irrelevant for the interference pattern.

To filter out a particular wavevector, usually a [collimator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiau4v4vbPrAhUPT30KHX1WAzMQFjAJegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCollimator&usg=AOvVaw2CSRIqi7Qd2MPsel5x8Mhf) is used. This ensures coherence (temporal and spatial). Next what you need to realise is that the interference pattern occurs due to each electron interfering with itself. This way there is always a phase relation between the two paths so to speak.